# Why are time-ordered Greens functions equal to retarded Greens functions at zero temperature?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, greens-functions, correlation-functions, chemical-potential

When I calculate a photon polarization diagram:
[image]

I get the same answer:

1. If I calculate it in equilibrium (retarded Greens functions) with finite chemical potential, in the limit of zero temperature, or
2. If I calculate it as a scattering amplitude (time-ordered Greens functions) in a particle bath $|\psi\rangle = \prod_{|\vec{p}|<p_F}c^\dagger_{\vec{p}}|0\rangle$.

The equality follows from a weird cancellation from the Fermi-Dirac distribution at zero temperature. Is there a theorem or some argument that this should happen in general (i.e. for more general correlation functions)?

Comment: Is this an agreement in an specific point, limit, e.g. coincident limit? and including numerical factors? Can you specify which type of bath? And the starting point of your computations perhaps...

Comment: doesn't it come from the fact that at zero-temperature the state is the vacuum, so the part of the retarded GF where the annihilation operator acts first contributes zero, and you are left with the same contribution as from the time-ordered GF?

Comment: He is computing about some bath in item 2 if I understand correctly

Comment: I calculate it in a bath of free electrons with 0-temperature Fermi-Dirac distribution: $\prod_{p<p_F}c^\dagger_{p}|0\rangle$

Comment: The equality (including all numerical factors) comes about because I get (for the scattering amplitude) a product of two FD distributions $f_{FD}(E_p+\omega)f_{FD}(E_p)$ which for $\omega>0$ and $T\to 0$ is exactly equal to $f_{FD}(E_p+\omega)$.

Comment: I found, upon Googling, a related question, including answers. Here it is: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/499638/

Comment: Wow, thanks! Interesting, though, that that post says "I have a hunch this not the case for two-particle Green's functions such as current-current correlation functions" while I am finding that it is the case!

Answer (score 0):

This is generally not the case. The reason is that, in addition to zero temperature, you are averaging over the vacuum state with zero particles, which is killed by annihilation operators.

Let us take time ordered Green's function at zero temperature:
$$
G^t(t,t')=\langle 0|T[c(t)c^\dagger(t')]|0\rangle=\\
\langle 0|c(t)c^\dagger(t')|0\rangle\theta(t-t') \pm \langle 0|c^\dagger(t')c(t)|0\rangle\theta(t'-t)
$$
and the retarded Green's function
$$
G^r(t,t')=\langle 0|[c(t)c^\dagger(t')]_\pm|0\rangle\theta(t-t')=\\
\langle 0|c(t)c^\dagger(t')|0\rangle\theta(t-t') \pm \langle 0|c^\dagger(t')c(t)|0\rangle\theta(t-t')
$$
If
$$ c(t)|0\rangle=0$$ the second terms in both equations are zero and the two functions are identical.

However, e.g., if the ground state is a Fermi sea filled up to its chemical potential the result is different.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was unclear. I am using a Fermi sea (that's what I meant by a bath of particles), and I get the same answer. I'll edit now to make this clearer.

Comment: @EricDavidKramer I see now. There might be a cancellation due to the sharpness of the Fermi level - but one has to go through the calculation to see it. Probably Fetter&Walecka discuss it somewhere, as they go through all the gory details.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what happens, the cancellation comes from the sharpness of the Fermi level. I was wondering if this was something general. I'll try to check F&W like you say.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you work in perturbation theory, at zero temperature the (unperturbed) state is the vacuum, meaning that $\psi_k(t)|0\rangle = 0$, so the only part of the retarded GF $$g^r(k, t) = \theta(t)\langle 0 | \psi_k^{\dagger}(0)\psi_k(t) + \psi_k(t) \psi_k^{\dagger}(0) | 0 \rangle$$ that survives will give the same result as the time-ordered one $$g(k, t) = \theta(t)\langle 0 | \psi_k(t)\psi_k^{\dagger}(0)|0\rangle + \theta(-t)\langle 0 | \psi^{\dagger}(0)\psi(t)|0\rangle$$

Comment: Thanks but I'm not using the vacuum. My state is the Fermi sea at zero temperature. I just edited to make this clearer.

Comment: can you share more details of your calculation? I think that if you normal-order then the contribution from the filled Fermi Sea should vanish, but I'm not sure and can't do it in my head right now

Comment: No, the normal ordering gives a Fermi-Dirac distribution $c^\dagger_p c_p|\psi\rangle = f_{FD}(E_p)|\psi\rangle$ (up to volume factors).

Comment: yeah but in normal order you subtract exactly that, no? $: A B : = A B - \langle 0 | AB |0\rangle$? I admit I forgot some of it and anyway I saw that you solved the issue from the other answer so nvm

Comment: Well we didn't really solve it, we just said that we should check in a book but I don't know if I'll find the answer there. About your point: I think in normal order you subtract only the vacuum contribution but if there is a contribution from particles in the state you must include it.